# How important are the songs in The Lord Of The Rings for the development of the story?

Tags: j-r-r-tolkien, the-lord-of-the-rings

There are many songs sung by different characters at various occasions in the book. I normally skip them since I found they normally don't tell more about the story and to be honest I don't quite enjoy them as a second language speaker of English. My understanding is in Middle Earth, people use songs to document or/and pass on knowledge and histories. So they should be indispensable to the world Tolkien created for us.

How do they contribute to the development of the story? Is this a common of way telling ancient stories in English literature?

Comment: See [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14901/3003) and its answers for a detailed analysis of one of the songs.

Comment: Highly related, from a different site: [In "The Lord of the Rings," what important background information is contained in the poems?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3492/31394) (with a long and detailed answer)